# Do the Vedas change through the Yugas?

Tags: vedas, yuga

I have heard that the Devas change through the Yugas, and that the Devas of the current Yuga are the children of Aditi.

Similarly, one often hears that the structure of music ragas change through the Yugas.

Do the Vedas change through the Yugas?

Comment: No. Vedas don't change through the yugas. We may not have complete set of hymns etc. but what we do have does not change over time/yugas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veda does not change with Yugas. It remains constant Kalpas after Kalpas. It is said that Lord Brahma, at the beginning of each Kalpa, recalls the Veda in his mind.

> 21. " The author of the Veda there is none ; (he) the fourfaced (God), at each succeeding revolution of a Kalpa, recalls to mind the Veda ;
>     and so does Manu remember the law (at each succeeding revolution of a
>     Kalpa).
> 22. " In conformity to the character of the age, the rules of law (suitable) for men differ from age to age. The rules for the Krita
>     differ from the Treta rules ; the Dvapara laws are not identical with
>     the Kali rules.
>
> *Parashara Smriti, Chapter 1, verses 21-22*

That means the same set of knowlege, known as the Vedas, is recalled at the beginning of every Kalpa by Lord Brahma. If Vedas were to change with Yugas or Kalpas, verse 21 would be meaningless.

As verse 22 states, the laws change with Yugas. But the Vedas remain the same that are being recalled by Brahma.